# How to deal with a request for a photocopy of my passport from the hiring company?

Tags: hiring-process, visa

I am an EU citizen (not British), who is looking for jobs in England. I have been in contact with an IT company which, after the first two interviews, asked me to send them a photocopy of my passport before a following technical test and a last final interview.

They are aware that I am an EU citizen and that I do not require visa sponsorship in order to work in GB.

I find this hiring process very suspect, and the early request for a copy of my passport in particular raised some questions:

- Is it normal for UK companies to request copies of candidates' passports before actually giving them a formal offer, or at least a draft of the contract?
- How should I react to this request?

Comment: @JoeStrazzere The request is for a photocopy. I'll edit the question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There will be a legal requirement to verify who you are (anti-moneylaundering laws), and that you have the right to work in the UK.  Taking a photocopy of passport is quite common for this (in case of later questioning by authorities/HMRC), and I've been asked to do this many times, both as perm and contractor.

So I wouldn't worry about it, you won't be able to progress without it.

Comment: "They are aware that I am an EU citizen" from the question.  Actually, they are probably only aware that you have told them that.  Now comes the proof, as this answer explains.

Comment: It's common here to require proof as well, good answer.